# Absolutely continuous maps measurable sets to measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-sets

Show that if $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous, then $f$ maps measurable sets to measurable sets.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because Lebesgue measure is [inner regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_regular_measure), given a Lebesgue measurable set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$, there exist a set $N$ of measure zero and a sequence of compact sets $\{K_n\}_{n\ge 1}$, such that 
$$E=N\cup(\cup_{n=1}^\infty K_n).$$ Since $f$ is continuous, $f(K_n)$ is compact for every $n\ge 1$; since $f$ is absolutely continuous, $f(N)$ is of measure zero. Therefore,
$$f(E)=f(N)\cup\big(\cup_{n=1}^\infty f(K_n)\big)$$ 
is measurable.

Comment: Can you provide a more elementary proof? This one is far from our course scope. Thanks.