# Borel set under inner product is borel

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a Borel set, $ e \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $||e|| = 1$ and define $P_e(a) = ea :\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ the inner product. Show that $P_e(A)$ is Borel.

We know that $P_e$ is continuous and Lipschitz with constant $1$, how does this help us in showing the statement?

Comment: To be clear, $P_e(a)$ is the inner product/dot product of $e$ and $a$? In that case [I'm not sure it's true..](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/603173/473276)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thanks for the respond. Yes I saw that post, but the book I'm reading somehow insists it is true and it doesn't give any explanation sadly. Do you think it is at least Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: [The image of a Lebesgue measurable set under a Lipschitz mapping is Lebesgue measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504487/a-lipschitz-transform-maps-measurable-set-to-measurable)

Comment: @FZan Thanks for the link, I've read the post but I'm still confused what did the author mean by "measurable", do you have an idea if were they talking about Lebesgue measurability?